# Normalizing slashes from a string path in java

Tags: java

```
String path = "/var/lib/////xen//images///rhel";
```

the number of slashes can be of any number. How to normalize the path in java like :

```
/var/lib/xen/images/rhel
```

Comment: Replace multiple occurrences of `/` with a single `/`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the built-in `String` method [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), with a regular expression `"/+"`, replacing one or more slashes with one slash:

```
path = path.replaceAll("/+", "/");
```

Comment: I am not much familiar with regex so I was trying "/*" instead of "/+"
:)

Answer (score 5):

You could use a `File` object to output the path specific to the current platform:

```
String path = "/var/lib/////xen//images///rhel";
path = new File(path).getPath();
```

Comment: Unfortunately just calling getPath seems to not always be enough,  ex: `new File(new File(new File("a//b"), "/"), "c").getPath()` =  `a/b//c`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [`CharMatcher`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html):

```
String simplifiedPath = CharMatcher.is('/').collapseFrom(originalPath, '/');
```

See: [Guava Explained > Strings > CharMatcher](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained#CharMatcher)

Answer (score 1):

A couple more options:

Calling File#getCanonicalPath happens to remove slashes, but it seemed to use this stack internally:

```
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.canonicalize(UnixFileSystem.java:172)
at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:618)
```

which seemed actually quite slow (at least on our particular system, which was Linux with GPFS underneath), so I couldn't use that.

So next I tried, from a deleted answer from Aubin (thanks! that he said he'd possibly seen in the JDK somewhere), this was actually quite a bit faster:

`path = new File( new File( path ).toURI().normalize()).getPath();`

Unfortunately underneath the toURI method seemed to call this:

```
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes0(Native Method)
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes(UnixFileSystem.java:242)
    at java.io.File.isDirectory(File.java:843)
    at java.io.File.toURI(File.java:732)
```

which was, again, a bit of slowdown.

See also java nio [Paths#normalize](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28053779/32453)

So at the end of the day, I ended up using the `replaceAll` methods from the others .